# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

problem: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
I wrote a code simple code  to connect with the database mysql and I have tried more times
Is this error  my java environment error or xamp error? How to fix this error?

```
package javaEE;

import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Example {
    
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/employee";
    
    // Database credentials
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS ="";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        
        try {
            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            
            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to database");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,"root","");
            
            //STEP 4: Execute a query
            System.out.println("Creating statement");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql;
            
            sql = "SELECT * FROM emp1";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            
            //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
            while(rs.next()) {
                //Retrieve by column name
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                int age = rs.getInt("age");
                String first = rs.getString("first");
                String last = rs.getString("last");
                
                //Display values
                System.out.print("ID:"+ id);
                System.out.print(", Age:"+ age);
                System.out.print(", First:"+ first);
                System.out.print(", Last:"+ last);
            }
            
            // STEP 6: Clean-up environment
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se) {
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            //Handle errors for class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            //finally block used to close resources
            try {
                if(stmt!=null)
                    stmt.close();
            }catch(SQLException se2) {
                
            }//nothing we can do
            try {
                if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }//end finally try
        }//end try
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }//end main

}//end Example
```

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd suggest that perhaps `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` does not exist, since that's the only class being loaded in this code. Please verify that the class exists.

Comment: If you have correctly defined variable `JDBC_DRIVER` why don't you use it when registering JDBC driver?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
static final String DB_URL ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```